# No puedo correr migraciones en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola hace tiempo subí a producción un proyecto en laravel, pero ahora después de mucho tiempo y quererlo ejecutar en local, al correr el comando php artisan migrate me aparece este error

ya revisé bien la configuración en mi archivo .env pero no puedo hacerlo correr. Ojalá alguien me pudiera orientar sobre qué pudiera estar pasando. Gracias!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Este es el error que me sale al correr **php artisan migrate**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El problema que te esta mostrando es que no hay conexión con la base de datos porque el usuario y/o contraseña que proporcionaste son incorrectos. Intenta `php artisan config:clear` e intenta correr nuevamente las migraciones.